# Android add layout inside custom layout

Tags: android, xml, syntax

I want to ask one question,some people can be find it ridiculous question.but its my need if possible. according to my `R&D` there is nothing i found related to this.

I have custom layout .

```
<com.example.customview.myview
            android:id="@+id/ex_view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:title="contact"
            custom:visibility="@integer/visible"/>
```

and i want to add one layout inside this custom layout i.e

```
   <com.example.customview.myview
                android:id="@+id/ex_view1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                custom:title="contact"
                custom:visibility="@integer/visible"
                here i want to add............................... />
```

I can not use `<include/>` tag inside any layouts `tags.`<.........here i need to add new layout......../>

if any `tag` available to do this please help me .if its not then please provide me fair information

thanks.

Comment: Syntactically impossible because unsupported by XML. Have you dealt with Android styles yet?

Comment: can you give me reason of downvotes....

Comment: Oh, I must revise my first comment maybe. Do you want to add a _child_ view? Then of course you do that ofter the end of the opening tag. `<myview android:id= etc> <child android:id etc /> </myview>`

Comment: Upvoting because the downvotes were completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

**I can not use  tag inside any layouts tags.<.........here i need to add new layout......../>**

you cannot do that because the name/value pairs inside <..../> are consider as attributes which is use to specify only the properties of the element.

The child elements must be always added between the start tag and end tag (`<tag> .... </tag>`) of an element.

And also it doesn't make any sense, because if u need your layout to have two child there is no meaning in adding it as a property of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to add a view as a child of your custom view.

First off make sure com.example.customview.myview extends ViewGroup. That will allow you to add child views to your custom view.

From there it depends on the implementation of your custom view.  If you are overriding onMeasure or onLayout you may need to measure and/or layout the child view.